# 127.0.0.1 redirects to example.com

Tags: networking, server, dns, nginx

127.0.0.1 redirects to example.com.

Surely I myself did something wrong and for 4 days already I can’t find the error. Sorry for that. Perhaps this mistake can be very visible since I am a beginner. I will be grateful if you help me find it.

```
running services:
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ - ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ + ]  networking
 [ + ]  nginx
 [ - ]  nginx-debug
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  postgresql
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  unicorn
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

and:

```
LISTEN   0         10                  0.0.0.0:3689             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("rhythmbox",pid=2650,fd=19))                                           
LISTEN   0         128           127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=4017,fd=13))                                     
LISTEN   0         5                 127.0.0.1:631              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=639,fd=7))                                                 
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:5432             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("postgres",pid=850,fd=7))                                              
LISTEN   0         10                     [::]:3689                [::]:*        users:(("rhythmbox",pid=2650,fd=20))                                           
LISTEN   0         5                     [::1]:631                 [::]:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=639,fd=6))
```

That's what i did so far:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
```

Comment: the problem is that if I set nginx, it starts up successfully, but 127.0.0.1  redirects to the example.com (same as when nginx is disabled as you can see above). I would like to disable that redirect

Comment: Look into the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and find symlink that leads to a file with "example.com" in it. Then remove this symlink (not the file!).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't have the sites-enabled folder. I linked the "sites-enabled" file with the file that is in the "sites-available" directory. Also, nginx now disabled but if I enter 127.0.0.1 I get redirected to example.com.

contents of my file:
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name 127.0.0.1;
 
 location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}
 location /static/ {
  demid /demid/myprojectdir;
 }
 
 location / {
  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
 }
}

Comment: Hello, I found that firefox redirects 127.0.0.1 to the example.com. However, Opera and Internet explorer shows my site. I think that something went wrong with Mozilla Firefox. Maybe this issue is not relevant for ubuntu. I think this question can be closed

Comment: I cleared my cashe and now it is working :/  Thank you Doug and Michal for your help